# How to access User Defined Runtime Attribute from the 'sender' object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have a `UIButton` in a Storyboard scene. The button has a User-Defined-RunTime-Attribute 'type'(String) configured. When pressed the button calls

`-(IBAction)pressedButton:(id)sender`

Will I be able to access the User-Defined-RunTime-Attribute from 'sender'?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes:

```
-(IBAction)pressedButton:(id)sender
{
    id value = [sender valueForKey:key];
}
```

---

Note that you cannot use a User Defined Run Time attribute, **unless you subclass UIButton and add it as a strong property**, for example

```
@interface UINamedButton : UIButton
@property (strong) NSString *keyName;
@end
```

If you set a User Defined Run Time attribute, and you have not done this, Xcode will badly crash unfortunately.

You can then get that value like

```
-(IBAction)clicked:(UIControl *)sender
    {
    NSString *test = @"???";

    if ( [sender respondsToSelector:@selector(keyName)] )
            test = [sender valueForKey:@"keyName"];

    NSLog(@"the value of keyName is ... %@", test);

    // if you FORGOT TO SET the keyName value in storyboard, that will be NULL
    // if it's NOT a UINamedButton button, you'll get the "???"

    // and for example...
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"idUber" sender:sender];
    // ...the prepareForSegue could then use that value in the button.

    // note that a useful alternative to
    // if ( [sender respondsToSelector:@selector(stringTag)] )
    // is... 
    // if ( [sender respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"stringTag")] )
    }
```