# In a UICollectionViewFlowLayout, set cell itemSize from Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

UICollectionViewFlowLayout...

```
@interface MediumBounce : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;
etc

@implementation MediumBounce

-(void)prepareLayout
    {
    [super prepareLayout];
    self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(92,144);
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

-(NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
    if(self.animator)
    etc etc etc
```

You have to set the **.itemSize**...

So I have many collection views, the cell size is 92.144.  However on another collection view, cell size is 200.144.

For that one, I just copy the class, name the new class MediumBounce200, and change the line of code that sets the **.itemSize** to 200.144.

Is there a better way?  Can you **read the size from the storyboard** somehow?

Or perhaps from the collectionVC, can you "reach down" and set that?  When?

(Note that the size which you make the cell **in the storyboard**, I'm pretty sure, actually doesn't matter: the size is set only by the code above in the FlowLayout.)

Answer (score 0):

For question `Can you read the size from the storyboard somehow?`

There is a way.

1. Choose the collection view in storyboard probably inside a viewController.
2. Set the view's runtime attributes in identity inspector -> `User Defined Runtime Attributes`

Comment: Hi Dopcn, U.D.R.A are often very useful, but I definitely do not want to use them here, I want to get it straight from the storyboard, how the designer shapes it on storyboard.  (BTW for U.D.R.A., here's an example if anyone's wondering http://stackoverflow.com/a/15007600/294884 )