# List of user defined runtime attributes available for an object in swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Is there a way (or a web site) to get the list of user defined runtime attributes for this or this object?

For example, there is the borderWidth for a button. I'm wondering if there is something like leftBorderWidth but don't really want to try all possible combination...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any property (including your own defined) that is of type `Bool`, `NSNumber`, `String`, `CGPoint`, `CGSize`, `CGRect`, `UIImage`, `UIColor` or `NSRange` can be set as user defined runtime attributes.

`borderWidth` is `button.layer` propery. `button.layer` class is `CALayer`. You can check out all `CALayer` properties here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/CALayer

Comment: How can we retrieve a custom property?

Comment: Actually, I think the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007542/how-to-access-user-defined-runtime-attribute-from-the-sender-object